# Is using an asynchronous NSURLConnection to do a fetch of a local file overkill?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, file-io, grand-central-dispatch

I'm wanting to read local JSON files off the disk (approx 5,000+ records/objects) and I have this code and am experimenting with Realm

I'd like to update my UI after it's finished loading and parsing it all; and I've tried some variants but the one I've got now seems like overkill.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fightersFilename withExtension:fightersFileExtension];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && data) {
         //call a delegate to send the data to your page from where it was called

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSError *error=nil;
            NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (!error) {
                    // Get realm and table instances for this thread
                    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm]; // Create realm pointing to default file

                    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

                    for (NSDictionary *fighterDict in result) {

                        DDLogVerbose(@"%@ %@", fighterDict[@"name"], fighterDict[@"filename"]);

                        Fighter *f = [[Fighter alloc] init];
                        f.name = fighterDict[@"name"];
                        f.filename = fighterDict[@"filename"];

                        [realm addObject:f];
                    }

                    // Commit the write transaction
                    // to make this data available to other threads
                    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

                    DDLogVerbose(@"%d fighters in realm",         [[Fighter allObjects] count]);
                }
            });
        });

    } else {
         //show alert that an error has occurred during downloading data from net.
        NSLog(@"JSON read error: %@", error);
    }
 }];

queue=nil;
```

The idea is that I'd like to read my JSON file, parse it and put it into objects and then once this is complete, update my UI or UX.

Given this, is the above a good solution?

Comment: Questions about improving working code should really be posted on codereview.stackexchange.com. SO is really for code that doesn't work.

Comment: You've got two variables named `queue`. You also should not check `error` before you check `data`.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying too hard.

In an async dispatch block on a background queue, read the file and parse it synchronously. When you're done, trigger an after function on the Main queue. I'll edit this shortly to add specific code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fightersFilename     
                                         withExtension:fightersFileExtension];
    NSAssert(url!=nil, @"URL not found for target resource.");
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSAssert(data!=nil, @"Reading data file failed.");
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                               error:&parseError];
    //TODO: Handle this sanely
    NSAssert(parseError==nil, @"Parsing JSON object failed."); 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self didFinishLoadingResource:result];
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that this technique contains all the threading to this single block of code. Nothing outside of this block needs to be thread-safe or even thread-aware.